# Is it possible to reuse cellForItemAtIndexPath:?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two collection views. They both use identical cell layouts but for other reasons they must be separate controllers. Currently when I make updates to `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` in one, I have to copy and paste the change to the other.

Is there a way for me to separate out this one method so I can make changes in one place and have them reflected in both controllers? One of the controllers is a UIViewController subclass. The other is a subclass of a custom UIViewController subclass.

Comment: Provide the code of both cellForItemAt, and explain to us why it HAS to be in separate VC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a Separate Data Source class then you can just link the collectionview data source to it.

Your data source will be like this

```
class CollectionViewDataSource: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {

var dataArray:[YourObjects]?

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArray!.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("YourCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    return cell
}
}
```

And you can cell it in your controller like this

```
lazy var collectionViewDataSource: CollectionViewDataSource = {
     return CollectionViewDataSource()
}()

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
didSet{
    collectionViewDataSource.dataArray = //Your array
    collectionView.dataSource = collectionViewDataSource
}
```

Comment: So to setup the cells I currently take data from an object I have stored in my controller. How can I pass that object to a separate data source class?

Comment: @kmcgrady see I attached an example

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kmcgrady welcome, in the same way you can also include collectionView delegate and make a custom delegate to communicate with your dataSourceDelegate class to your controller for which object is tapped

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this

Suppose there are 2 viewcontroller vc1 and vc2 and 2 collectionview cv1 and cv2

Make a separate class 
CollectionDelegate cD

now set datasource of both collectionview to this newly made CollectionDelegate

like

```
 cv1.dataSource = cD 
cv2.datasource = cD
```

Implement you cellForItemAtIndexPatha and other data source method in CollectionDelegate class